# Gradle и IntelliJ не загружают PostgreSQL JDBC зависимости

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

```
try {
    DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance());
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    url.
            append("jdbc:postgresql:").
            append("table");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url.toString(), "postgres", "asdasdasd12");
    return connection;
} catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

получаю исключение в строке

```
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance());
```

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:258)   at
>   ua.kiev.makson.database.DBService.getPostgresqlConnection(DBService.java:36)
>     at ua.kiev.makson.database.DBService.(DBService.java:12)  at
>   ua.kiev.makson.Testing.main(Testing.java:14)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

мой **build.gradle**:

```
group 'ua.kiev.makson'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'

    compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
}
```

[image: jar]
[image: gradle]

Подскажите, что надо исправить.

Comment: jdbc драйвера версии 4 и выше не обязательно регистрировать в DriverManager. попробуйте без этой строки         DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance());

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql:table - все равно ошибку выкидывает

Comment: А как собираете\запускаете проект? Через градл?

Comment: @Alexandr после того как добавляю зависимости в build.gradle в модуле intellij.gradle нажимаю обновить. после  проект запускаю через intellij, main и там вызываю нужный метод.

Comment: попробуйте удалить кэш и пересобрать проект. У меня с вашим build.gradle все заработало

Comment: @makson попробуйте собрать и запустить проект через gradle

Comment: Вы пробовали вместо compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4' написать runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4' ?

Comment: @Russtam все равно ошибку эту выкидывает

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov переустановил gradle 3 версию, сделал `gradle build --refresh-dependencies`, в модуле идеи `gradle/build/clean` потом `gradle/build/build` потом запускаю через зеленую кнопку main() - выкидывает ошибку, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я просто создал новый gradle проект в idea. версия у меня ultimate 2016.1.1

Comment: Idea 2016.2.2 - всё заработало с вашим build.gradle. Единственное что Idea не понравился градл убунты, т.к. не было прав на запись, поставил градл 3.0 в отдельную папку. И я создавал не в Idea, а создал ручками, а потом открыл в Idea.

Comment: @makson если запускать через идею то в первой строчке будут видны параметры запуска, начинаются так: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port ...` Проверьте что в параметре -classpath есть библиотека `C:\Users\\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\postgresql\postgresql\9.1-901-1.jdbc4\9bfabe48876ec38f6cbaa6931bad05c64a9ea942\postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar`

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov пересоздал проект и все работает норм. скорей всего при создании проекта в первый раз что-то напортачил, так как первый раз создавал gradle проект